# Threaded view in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I want to view my Gmail messages in threaded view like Google Groups threaded view.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can either have "Conversation View on" which is the Gmail threaded conversation view (and the default) or you can have "Conservation View off" which is the more traditional e-mail representation of your messages.

Look under [Gmail Settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#settings) on the "General" tab.

Answer (score 2):

When you have "Conversation view" switched on (see Al Everett's answer) and are viewing an email thread, you can click "Expand all" on the right side of the page to see all the emails at once.